# How to remove hyperlink symbol in latex?

Tags: latex

I am trying to make a new CV on overleaf using the modern Deedy template - [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-deedy/cxtjgrmpsrvh)

Currently, it looks like this

[image]

Under the first project - desktop application for pair trading, I don't have a link to provide for the code so I just want to remove the small symbol which leads to another link.

In the code, the segment for this part is like this

```
\projectHeadingwithoutLink{DESKTOP APPLICATION FOR PAIR TRADING}{https://github.com/devangmukherjee/random-zomato-restaurant}{Python, Selenium, Tkinter, Yahoo Finance API}

Made a desktop application for finding correlation between two stocks and looking for divergence using density curve formula which sold multiple copies at 500 USD each.\\


\sectionsep
  
\projectHeading{LOCATION BASED RESTAURANT SUGGESTION}{https://github.com/devangmukherjee/random-zomato-restaurant}{NodeJS, ExpressJS, Mongoose, MongoDB}

A full-stack website which can suggest the best restaurants in an area using Zomato API and filtered according to user ratings.\\

\sectionsep
```

and the section of `projectHeading` looks like this

```
% Create project heading. Parameters: Name, link, Tech stack
\newcommand{\projectHeading}[3]{\Project{#1}{#2}
\descript{#3}\\}
```

How can I edit it to remove the hyperlink symbol while keeping the names of the languages on the right?

Comment: please add a compilable [mre] to your question, so we don't have to puzzle together you fragments before even starting to work on a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modify the `resume-openfont.cls` file.

At line 125 of the `resume-openfont.cls` comment the  command `\faExternalLink`, which inserts such symbol and the link. The `\Project` command is the one that inserts the hyperlink.

```
% Project command
    \newcommand{\Project}[2]{
    \runsubsection{%
    \href{#2}{\uppercase{#1}} %\,\faExternalLink}
    }
        \hfill
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!